# Nested loop in a batch file for cleanup

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

This should be pretty simple..

We have the following structure on a Windows server:

- D:\vendor1
- D:\vendor2
- D:\tomcat1
- D:\tomcat2

And we need to archive and manage logs. This structure would be my preference:

```
REM REMOVE ANY ZERO-BYTE FILES
FOR %%d IN (1,2) DO (
    FOR /r D:\vendor%%d\logs %%X IN (*) DO IF %%~zX LSS 1 (DEL /Q "%%X")
    FOR /r D:\vendor%%d\other_logs %%X IN (*) DO IF %%~zX LSS 1 (DEL /Q "%%X")
    FOR /r D:\tomcat%%d\logs %%X IN (*) DO IF %%~zX LSS 1 (DEL /Q "%%X")
)
pause
```

And the odd thing is that this does not seem to work either.

```
REM REMOVE ANY ZERO-BYTE FILES
for %%d in (1,2) do call :process_dir %%d
goto :eof

:process_dir
FOR /r D:\vendor%1\logs %%X IN (*) DO IF %%~zX LSS 1 (DEL /Q "%%X")
FOR /r D:\vendor%1\other_logs %%X IN (*) DO IF %%~zX LSS 1 (DEL /Q "%%X")
FOR /r D:\tomcat%1\logs %%X IN (*) DO IF %%~zX LSS 1 (DEL /Q "%%X")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I got the call process to work just like you have it.

Comment: Your first approach cannot work as `for /R` does not accept other `for` variables in the path given after `/R`; neither does it accept delayed-expansion-variables; you can use only normal percent variables or argument references like `%1`; for me your second approach works just fine... Do your real paths contain white-spaces? try quoting every path properly...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out..

```
REM REMOVE ANY ZERO-BYTE FILES
FOR %%d IN (1,2) DO (
    SET /A PTR=%%d
    FOR /r D:\vendor%PTR%\logs %%X IN (*) DO IF %%~zX LSS 1 (DEL /Q "%%X")
    FOR /r D:\vendor%PAR%\other_logs %%X IN (*) DO IF %%~zX LSS 1 (DEL /Q "%%X")
    FOR /r D:\tomcat%PTR%\logs %%X IN (*) DO IF %%~zX LSS 1 (DEL /Q "%%X")
)
pause
```

The key here is the `SET /A`

Comment: Hmm.  Still does not work for me. Not even if I use delayed expansion.